# OpenCV same cordinates different points?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, colors

I am trying to get color from inside of the red circle and change color of the big circle located on top-left as seen on [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpER9.jpg). And as seen on screen shot, the color of the big circle is not same with what is in the red circle, it is getting color a little bit left from the red circle. I gave the same cordinates, how to fix it?

Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnTouchListener {

    private CameraBridgeViewBase cameraManager;

    private BaseLoaderCallback callBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            cameraManager.enableView();
        }
    };

    Mat mRgba;
    double[] renk;
    int r,g,b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0, this, callBack);
        }

        cameraManager = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.kamera);
        cameraManager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cameraManager.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        cameraManager.setCameraIndex(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        renk = mRgba.get(mRgba.width()/2, (mRgba.height()/10)*8);
        Imgproc.circle(mRgba, new Point(mRgba.width()/2, (mRgba.height()/10)*8), 10, new Scalar(255,0,0));

        r = (int) renk[0];
        g = (int) renk[1];
        b = (int) renk[2];

        Imgproc.circle(mRgba, new Point(0, 0), 100, new Scalar(r,g,b), 100);

        return mRgba;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide the input image. your code looks ok, the color cannot come from left of the circle

Comment: I have tried it in two different devices but the result is same. What else could cause that situation? @piglet

Comment: provide the image you are talking about, not just a screenshot from your phone. so you want to tell me that you have the very same colour on two different devices with two different pictures from two different cameras?

Comment: the result is same before. It is picking color anywhere else. @piglet

Comment: ok, read again the topic @piglet

Comment: if you have a solution to your question you have two options. a) you delete your question or better b) you write an answer to your question. don't edit your question so it contains the answer... also you might want to say more than one sentence that states something obvious. for me it doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: Dear @Piglet, I don't know what in your daily life causes that your unsympathetic answers but it is beneficial to try not to be smart aleck to keep good impression about you in people's mind. Please check the writer of the topic that you want to answer. If it's me, please go away calmly even if you know it. Thank you.

Comment: just delete or improve your post. as is it is useless. please read [ask] if you don't understand why.. I just told you that you don't provide enough information and that you should not write an answer inside a question. no reason to be disrespectful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I figured that thing. Point(x,y) = column, row.